# ListView lagging on phone but not on tablet

Tags: android, listview, lag

My application consists of a ListView with images. On my phone it lags, and android monitor shows memory usage 380mb , while on my tablet which is a very cheap tablet with low specs, memory usage is somewhere around 50mb and i get no lag. I am planning to optimize my ListView, but until then I am just curious if anyone knows why this is happening?

Comment: mb ? What is mb?

Comment: @greenapps megabytes

Comment: can you post some code? there is no way to help from just this description

Comment: @BaiRadule Just for your information, in case if you don't know: 'm' represents milli (1/1000) and for mega (1000000) 'M' is the standard. Similarly 'b' represents bit while for byte 'B' is used. So it should be MB not mb.

Comment: It depends a lot on the image size. It will lag if you load the images at their real size, but you display them to a much smaller size. In this case, a low specs doesn't mean bad: a new phone has more pixels that should load and usually the images are displayed at a better quality, thus much more work for them. I think that you should post the adapter and an image that you are using in order to receive a proper answer.

Comment: @IulianPopescu thank you, this is the only answer that makes sense. I used glide to load the images in order to optimize it, and now it's working perfectly

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked if you are running any other processes in the background? This could be the problem. It could also be caused by a lack of code optimization.

Comment: well the code is the same on both devices, even if it lacks optimization,why would it run smooth on tablet and laggy on phone?

Comment: Again, have you checked if there are any other processes running on the phone?

Comment: Yes, i checked, i even rebooted the phone

Comment: My only guess is that it is either a old, un-optimized version of Android, or some other process that is making it slow. Like Bluetooth, Wifi etc..

Comment: My phone has android 7 ,other applications are working fine